# Steering Wheel code in Unity Engine using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, 2d-games

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class SteeringWheel : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{

    public bool Wheelbeingheld = false;
    public RectTransform Wheel; //makes a gameobject treat like an object like of a rectangular shape, so that we could use many functionalities of the RECT feature, such as worldToScreenPoint, object.position, etc.
    public float WheelAngle = 0f;
    public float LastWheelAngle = 0f; //the previous angle of the wheel 
    private Vector2 center;
    public float MaxSteerAngle = 200f;
    public float ReleaseSpeed = 300f;
    public float OutPut; // the output angle with which the steering wheel is rotated.

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!Wheelbeingheld && WheelAngle != 0f)
        {
            float DeltaAngle = ReleaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime; //distance = speed * time; ...as angle is the distance between from and to position on the axis of the object.
            if(Mathf.Abs(DeltaAngle)>Mathf.Abs(WheelAngle)) //Mathf.abs - removes the negative sign if there in the float value and return the ABSOLUTE value.
            WheelAngle = 0f; //wheelangle will always end to 0. not more or less than that.
            else if (WheelAngle>0f) //wheel coming back code how it will through these values and functions, so that wheels comes back to (0,0) position like that.
            WheelAngle -= DeltaAngle; //wheel back, while on right side steered as  wheel angle greater than 0
            else
            WheelAngle += DeltaAngle; //wheel back, while on left side steered as  wheel angle greater than 0
        }
        Wheel.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -WheelAngle); //the animation - how the wheel will rotate if it will. Or Vector3.back * wheelAngle; wheel angle will be 0; the wheel is rotating on z axis so thats why written on the z axis place; and minus sign on wheel angle, becuz the wheel has to come back from wherever it is in the opposite direction.
        OutPut = WheelAngle/MaxSteerAngle; //returns value through rotation of wheel, from -1 to 1.
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
    {
        Wheelbeingheld = true;
        center = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(data.pressEventCamera, Wheel.position); //world to screen point. 
        LastWheelAngle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.up, data.position - center); //Syntax: Vector2.Angle(Vector2 from, Vector2 to)
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        float NewAngle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.up, data.position - center);
        if((data.position - center).sqrMagnitude >= 400) 
        {
            if(data.position.x > center.x)
            WheelAngle += NewAngle - LastWheelAngle;
            else
            WheelAngle -= NewAngle - LastWheelAngle;
        }
        WheelAngle = Mathf.Clamp(WheelAngle, -MaxSteerAngle, MaxSteerAngle); //Clamp(float value, float min, float max)
        LastWheelAngle = NewAngle;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
    {
        OnDrag(data); // Performs one last DragEvent, just in case. As when you leave the wheel, the wheel rotates back, so till then also it will assess the wheel angle and run the code of drag.
        Wheelbeingheld = false;
    }
}
```

Got this code from somewhere online and it works absolutely fine and as expected. The comments are of my own for my understanding. Check if possible if I have understood things right.
I am not able to understand 5 things for which I would love if anyone helps me with it:

1. "Wheel Angle" and "Last Wheel Angle" - Why is it needed if "New Angle" accurately does the job? And why not also put that in update function?
2. What is the speed as in frames per second of "OnPointerDown" or "...Up" and "OnDrag" functions if refreshed. Do they compare to Update or FixedUpdate?
3. What is data.pressEventCamera and why is it used? It's not even in the syntax of "WorldToScreenPoint" function.
4. What does "sqr.Magnitude" actually do? I have a guess but want to confirm.
5. Why is Delta Angle used and what actually is with that name?

Hoping for satisfying answers soon.

Answer (score 0):

1: It is on `OndDrag` to stop the wheel from spinning when it has not been rotated by the user. If it was in `Update` it would rotate every frame. The newangle doesn't take into consideration the current angle, so is then added to the current angle to give a smoother rotation.

2: `OnPointerDown` is called when the pointer is pressed down on the scrollbar.

3: The camera associated with the last `OnPointerPress` event.

4: `sqr.Magnitude` is, well, the magnitude of the vector squared

5: delta anything means the change in. This is the change in the steering wheels angle.

**Please do note that most of these answers came from the unity docs - you could always do a search on them: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html**